# ggplot2 programmically using aes_ and ..x../stat(x) return error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to turn this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, fill = stat(x))) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'blue', high = 'yellow')
```

into a function something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
plotfn <- function (data, col_interest) {
  g <- ggplot(data, aes_(x = col_interest, fill = stat(x))) +
       geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
       scale_fill_gradient(low = 'blue', high = 'yellow')
  return(g)
}

plotfn(mtcars, "cyl")
```

I'd like to create a function for this and automate my code to reduce bugs and line counts but I don't know the equivalent `..x..` or `stat(x)` for `aes_`. The guide and notes on `aes_` does not talk about this either.

Thanks.

Reference to `stat()`: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat.html

Reference to `aes_`: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html

Comment: Note that `aes_()` is soft-deprecated. It is recommended that you use tidy-evaluation going forward.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish by using `aes_` here?

Comment: Can you clarify your use case?  For example, maybe you are trying to put this in a function and then pass the x variable to it  If that was the case you don't need `aes_()`.  Instead you can use `aes()` with tidy evaluation like `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = {{ var }}, fill = stat(x)) )`.  Then you could pass `cyl` to that function.

Comment: @MrFlick I'm reusing the same ggplot2 code over for 8 data set and each data set uses the similar ggplot parameters and functions (aes, geom_histogram, scale_fill_gradient, guides, theme). I'd like to create a function for this and pass in just the parameters and it return a ggplot2 function so I can build on top of this.

Comment: How are you passing in the parameters? Strings? Symbols? As @aosmith pointed out you are probably going to want to use the standard `aes()` with the new embrace syntax for popping in variables.

Comment: @aosmith Not exactly like what you stated. The `x` in `stat(x)` is some kind of special variable that is referring to something that stat calculate. I'm not trying to pass a param via a function. I'm trying to figure out how to use `..x..` or `stat(x)` in `aes_` just like how `aes` uses it but within a function.

Comment: @MrFlick Strings. I tried @aosmith way but I can't get `stat(x)` or `..x..` to work. I lack sufficient knowledge to know what those special var in ggplot2 does other than it makes my histogram bar a gradient color...

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would use what you are proposing in a function?  I think right now we're just guessing at what you *might* be doing with this.  You'll likely get more concrete advice if you show the kind of function you are trying to make and what kind of values you are passing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass in strings, then you would need to use `rlang::sym` and the `!!` (bang-bang) operator

```
library(ggplot2)
plotfn <- function (data, col_interest) {
  g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = !!rlang::sym(col_interest), fill = stat(x))) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = 'blue', high = 'yellow')
  return(g)
}
```

or you can use the special `.data` variable

```
plotfn <- function (data, col_interest) {
  g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = .data[[col_interest]], fill = stat(x))) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = 'blue', high = 'yellow')
  return(g)
}

plotfn(mtcars, "cyl")
```

With symbols you just use `{{}}`

```
plotfn <- function (data, col_interest) {
  g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = {{col_interest}}, fill = stat(x))) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = 'blue', high = 'yellow')
  return(g)
}

plotfn(mtcars, cyl)
```

This way you leave the rest of the `aes()` unchanged to `stat()` continues to work.

Comment: You might also mention the `.data` pronoun for strings: `aes(x = .data[[col_interest]], fill = stat(x))`.

Comment: Good point @aosmith. I always forget about that one because it doesn't look as "nice" to me. I've updated the answer (though at this point there's surely a dup out there)